# I can't recover a Calendar using getSerializableExtra of an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, serializable

I putExtras in Activity A:

```
notificationIntent.putExtra(KEY_ID, id);
notificationIntent.putExtra(KEY_CALENDAR, day);
A.logCalendar("calendar: ", day); // the Calendar is not null at this point
```

I getExtras en Activity B:

```
int id = intent.getIntExtra(Constantes.KEY_ID, 0);
A.b("My id: " + id); // The id is recovery
Calendar time = (Calendar) intent.getSerializableExtra(Constantes.KEY_CALENDAR);
if (time == null)
    A.b("null calendar"); // The calendar is always null, WHY?
```

What I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you do that? Just create one calendar in each activity. `Calendar` is only a helper for date and time calculation. If you want to pass a point in time, use the `java.util.Date` class or the milliseconds as `long`.

Comment: Sometimes we are so close of the tree that we can't see the forest. Thanks. I'll use a long with milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can't serialize entire Calendar object and send it using Extra. You can send only primitives, arrays and String. You may need to consider alternatives like Parcellable.